# Sum over permutations of linear combinations of a complete set of conjugates

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, galois-theory

While going through [Wikipedia's proof of the Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem#Lindemann.E2.80.93Weierstrass_theorem), I conjectured the following result:

> Let $a_1,...,a_N \in K$ be not all $0$ and let $f$ be a separable polynomial of degree $N >0$ with a splitting field $L$ over $K$.
>   Let $\alpha_1 ,..., \alpha_N$ be all conjugate zeros of $f$. Let $S_N$ be the symmetric group.
>   Then the sum $\sum_{\sigma \in S_N} a_1 \sigma( \alpha_1 ) + ... + a_N \sigma(\alpha_N)$ splits into at least $N! / ord(Gal(L|K))$ sums of complete sets of conjugates.

Here's my attempt at proving it:

Since $f$ is separabel with splitting field $L$ over $K$, $Gal(L|K)$ can be viewed as a subgroup of the symmetric group $S_N$.
Define $n := ord(Gal(L|K))$ (where ord() means order). Let $A := \{ s_1,...,s_{N! / n} \} \subseteq S_N$ be a system of elements, such that $s_1 A \cup ...
\cup s_{N! / n} A = S_N$, which exists because $Gal(L|K)$ can be viewed as a subgroup of $S_N$. Every $\sigma \in S_N$ can then be written as $g_i \circ s_j$ for a $g_i \in Gal(L|K)$ and a $s_j \in A$.
Therefore we can rewrite the sum as:
\begin{align*}
&\sum_{\sigma \in S_N} a_1 \sigma( \alpha_1 ) + ... + a_N \sigma(\alpha_N) \\ = &\sum_{s_j \in A} \sum_{g_i \in Gal(L|K)} a_1 (g_i \circ s_j) ( \alpha_1 ) + ... + a_N g_i \circ s_j (\alpha_N) \\ = &\sum_{s_j \in A} \sum_{g_i \in Gal(L|K)} g_i (a_1 s_j ( \alpha_1 ) + ... + a_N s_j (\alpha_N)) 
\end{align*}

Now let $H_{s_j} = \{h_1,...,h_m \}$ be the galois group of the minimal polynomial of $a_1 s_j ( \alpha_1 ) + ... + a_N s_j (\alpha_N)$. By the fundamental theorem of galois theory, we have that $H_{s_j}$ is a subgroup of $Gal(L|K)$. 
Now let $B := \{ \tau_1 ,..., \tau_M \}$ be a system of elements, such that $\tau_1 H_{s_j} \cup ... \cup \tau_M H_{s_j} = Gal(L|K)$, which exists because $ H_{s_j}$ is a subgroup of $Gal(L|K)$.
Now we can write the sum as:
$$\sum_{s_j \in A} \sum_{h_i \in H_{s_j}} \sum_{\tau_k \in B} (h_i \circ \tau_k) (a_1 s_j ( \alpha_1 ) + ... + a_N s_j (\alpha_N))$$
Each sum $ \sum_{\tau_k \in B} (h_i \circ \tau_k) (a_1 s_j ( \alpha_1 ) + ... + a_N s_i (\alpha_N)) $ is a sum over a complete set of conjugates, and there are $\sum_{s_j \in A} \#H_{s_j}$ of them. Since $\#H_{s_j} \geq 1$ it follows, that there are at least $\#A = \frac{\#S_N}{\#Gal(L|K)} = \frac{N!}{ord(Gal(L|K))} $ such sums of complete sets of conjugates.

Does anyone see any mistakes in my reasoning? Is there a cleaner way to prove this? Any feedback is gladly appreciated!